# Printing selenium search results

Tags: python, selenium

I've written the following code to search the UNSPSC search page.  This script works, but I'm having difficulty extracting the actual results.  Adding to the code below, it should then extract "Toy balloons or balls"

```
from selenium import webdriver

# from selenium.common import exceptions

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

opts = Options()
#opts.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    firefox_options=opts,
    firefox_binary='path/Firefox/firefox.exe',
    executable_path='./geckodriver.exe',
    )
driver.get("https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/")
search = driver.find_element_by_id("dnn_ctr1535_UNSPSCSearch_txtsearchCode")
search.send_keys("60141001")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

To Extract the text induce `WebDriverWait`  and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and use the following `xpath`

```
driver.get("https://www.unspsc.org/search-code/")
search = driver.find_element_by_id("dnn_ctr1535_UNSPSCSearch_txtsearchCode")
search.send_keys("60141001")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
print(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@id='dnn_ctr1535_UNSPSCSearch_gvDetailsSearchView']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]"))).text)
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: I'd advice to use `//tr[td='60141001'][1]/td[2]` just to be very sure, value can be parameterized